# How to use Vuetify elements as Inertia links

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vite, inertiajs

I am using Vuetify 3 + Inertia/vue 1 + vite 4 in my project. There are a lot of vuetify elements like `v-btn` or `v-card` which need to be linked to other pages.

When I use the `href` props of these elements the link will not be an Inertia link and when the user clicks in them, the page is fully reloaded. I tried using the `as` prop of the `Link` element in Inertia as following:

```
import {VBtn} from "vuetify/components";
...
<Link :href="route('home')" as="VBtn">Home</Link>
```

The HTML result: `<vbtn>Home</vbtn>`

I also tried:

```
import {VBtn} from "vuetify/components";
...
<Link :href="route('home')" as="{VBtn}">Home</Link>
```

The result: `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('{VBtn}') is not a valid name.`

Also tried this as well:

```
<Link :href="route('home')" as="{v-btn}">Home</Link>
```

The result: `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('{v-btn}') is not a valid name`

I also tried embedding the vuetify elements inside the `<link>` element but that results in invalid HTML (for example  tag inside  tag) and corrupts the styling of vuetify components.

Comment: How can I use inertia route in a v-list-item?

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party, but maybe someone in the future will stumble here.

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { router } from '@inertiajs/vue3';

const navigateTo = (routeName: string) => {
  router.visit(route(routeName));
}
</script>

<template>
  <v-list>
    <v-list-item
      title="demo"
      :href="route(welcome)"
      @click.prevent.stop="navigateTo(welcome)"
     />
  </v-list>
</template>
```

By also passing the href you should be able to use vue router's active class.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of `$inertia.get()` and use `@click` event. Your `v-list-item` should look like this:

```
 <v-list-item @click="$inertia.get('/home')">Home</v-list-item>
```

Should work to other components such as `v-card`, `v-btn`, `v-icon`, `v-sheet` etc. you name it!

Another option is you can import `router` from `@inertiajs/vue3` and use it in your methods dynamically:

```
import { Link, router } from "@inertiajs/vue3";

const openPage = (path) => { 
 router.get(path);
}
```

Checkout the docs https://inertiajs.com/manual-visits

Answer (score -2):

Maybe if you use the VBtn component directlty instead the Link element:

```
...
import {VBtn} from "vuetify/components";

<v-btn variant="text"  :href="route('home')">Home </v-btn>           
...
```

Also can help you the VBtn documentation
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-btn/

Comment: This reloads the page, which is not the inertia way.